# Problem with Testing and Debuging of Android Apps

Tags: sql, android, debugging, sqlite

Actucally I have two related questions concerning Android Errors. I released an update of an app which worked ok before and works in the current version on my Nexus One, G1 and the emulator. However I get a lot of error logs through the Android market console since this last update and I can't reproduce the error. The app is quite simple with only two activities, so it should be quite easy to test the App manually. However there are often Errors which I did not find before releasing.

So the first questions is, is there a way to test more deaply?

My second question is concerning the current error specifically. There seems to be a problem with the SQLite database wich can't find a table. I guess the database can't be created in the first place thus the error. Here's the stack trace:

BTW. There were three users with a Desire HD with complaints. Is there a bug known?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {XXX/XXX}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: main_ger: , while compiling: SELECT _id, code, area FROM main_ger
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3394)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2179)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: main_ger: , while compiling: SELECT _id, code, area FROM main_ger
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1301)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1256)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1336)
at XX.XXX.DataBaseHelper.fetchAll(DataBaseHelper.java:190)
at XX.XXX.fillData(mainactivity.java:240)
at XX.XXX.onResume(mainactivity.java:522)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1238)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3904)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
... 12 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to fully uninstall your application from your development phone and reinstall it from scratch? Maybe your database creation method is wrong?

Comment: Yes, tried that several times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there are some more people with this problem:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-4/#comment-43655

[Database handling stoped working on Android 2.2.1 (Desire HD 1.72.405.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651797/database-handling-stoped-working-on-android-2-2-1-desire-hd-1-72-405-3)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=895942

The Dev in the following article seems to have found a solution. I will try it soon and let you know. Is there anyonw with a desire hd who could help me test it?

http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a known bug....I have a Desire HD but it's unrooted so I cannot really verify what's happening inside the FS. (data folder).
My logcat it's the same :(

Comment: do you have problems with other apps, too?

Answer (score 1):

We have exact same problem. We receive at lease 5 reports per day from our users with this problem. Our app has been around for a year,and we never had this problem before until Desire HD came to the market.

Comment: Please let us know if you figure the reason out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android supports automated unit testing. Please see this article:
[Android Developer Reference: Testing Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html)

As to the SQLLite bug, what makes you think that there was an attempt to create the database? Wouldn't that have thrown an exception? Do you verify that the database exists and create it if it does not when your activity resumes? And do you recreate the tables if they don't exist?

Comment: Yes I tried to secure error during the creation of the database with exeptions. But as I said I cannot reporoduce the error. So I can just guess what could have happened...