# "Error: file is encrypted or is not a database" when opening Android SQLite db from external app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm experimenting with a SQLite database to hold logging information from a messaging app.

I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper and forcing the db onto the SD card of an *unrooted* device using:

```
public LogDatabase(Context context, String dbname) {
  super(context, 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
      "/" + dbname, null, 3);
}
```

This appears to work fine: the database grows appropriately and the app doesn't throw any exceptions when writing to it.

The problem arises when I USB-mount the device and try to open the database from an external app (for example, sqlite3 from an Ubuntu command line). The error is always the same: "Error: file is encrypted or is not a database".

Is there something hinky about Android's treatment of SQLite? Or am I missing something fundamentally broken about the way I'm managing the db?

Edit: The original device in question is a HTC Desire S running v2.3.5.

Edit: I've re-run the test on an alternative device (Motorola ET1 running v2.3.4) and the problem *does not* occur. I can mount the device via Ubuntu and browse the database at will via the sqlite3 command line.

Comment: It is possible to specify encryption on a SQLite database, however it's not enabled by default. Have you tried copying the database off the device to your PC, and then locally opening it using the cmd prompt?

Comment: @Pete - thanks for your reply, yes I've tried that with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I appear to have found the answer. Once I suspected that it might be vendor-specific I found this Stack question:

[Sqlite issues with HTC Desire HD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718934/sqlite-issues-with-htc-desire-hd)

which suggested that HTC might have enabled write-ahead logging (WAL) on their devices.

Supposing that was true I pulled a very recent build of SQLite and built v3.7.14, which happily, can successfully open the problem database. This is as opposed to v3.6.22 of SQLite which could not.