# Android: Disk I/O error during query in MediaStore

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mediastore

I am having a problem with quering MediaStore provider. This issue is common for some devices rare but I cannot reproduce it myself. I have it from user crashlogs. I found out that it might be related to device. Some developers had problems with accessing their DB on HTC Desire ([Database handling stoped working on Android 2.2.1 (Desire HD 1.72.405.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651797/database-handling-stoped-working-on-android-2-2-1-desire-hd-1-72-405-3)). My issue also occurs on HTC Desire (and some other devices). BUT it isn't my DB so I cannot change the path or change a way how MediaStore DB is managed.

This is a callstack I get:

```
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 522)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:182)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
```

The query is called in a standard way:

```
contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null);
```

It occurs in all situations in my app where I do a query to MediaStore.

To be specific about devices:GT-I9003,HTC Desire,AM_Stick02,X10.Dual,HTC Sensation,C5155
 and APIs:4.1.1;4.2.2;4.0.4,4.1.2

Please, do you have any idea what it can cause or do you know some workaround for these devices ?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

this issue may be connected with this:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite.git/+/6ab557bdc070f11db30ede0696888efd19800475%5E!/#F0