# Unreadable sqlite3 file

Tags: android, sqlite

I've just written my first android-app (https://sourceforge.net/projects/cashcontroll/).
It's a little budget-control tool to control my expenses.

Everything works fine. 
Because of the fact that this is quit important data for me I've created a backup function where the whole db-file is stored to the sd card.

And now the weird thing happens:
With my first android (htc desire , android 2.2 Build 2.29) )I can make a backup, transfer it to the pc an analize it with a db tool like navicat. I can also change it an dump it back to the sd card an import it afterwards into my app.

When I then copy the same file to the sd card of my second android (htc desire hd, android 2.29) I can also import it an use it in my app.
As soon as I do a backup on my second android I can't read the database in any other tool (e.g. navicat oder my first android). It can be used in the original device (my second mobile) though.I can also open it with a text editor (e.g nano) but nothing else.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Ueli

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you 1) transfer the db file to your computer, 2) open it with navicat and 3) transfer it back to your device. If you can't read it, it probably means that navicat modified it.

Comment: Hello gulbrand

Thanks for answering.
You misunderstood. With one of my cell-phones (the older htc desiere) everything works just write.

I can export the file to the pc, modify it an re-import it again.

But as soon as my second cell-phone (the htc desire hd) touches the file, I can't read it in any other application except the desire hd.
So it's not possible to exchange the db from htc desire hd to the htc desire but it works the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the HTC Desire HD. Have a look at [Database handling stoped working on Android 2.2.1 (Desire HD 1.72.405.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651797/database-handling-stoped-working-on-android-2-2-1-desire-hd-1-72-405-3) and [Problem with Testing and Debuging of Android Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585790/problem-with-testing-and-debuging-of-android-apps) .