# How to resolve table no such table exception in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

I developed an android application with sqlite database.Presently my app is in google play.Here i am getting some reported issues like "no such table" while executing select query.
Actually i copied my database from Assets folder. Here i followed below given link to copy my database 
[Here is the link what i followed](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

And by code is like

```
public class DbFromAssets  extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {  
    private String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/package/databases/";
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
    private final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public DbFromAssets(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        try
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            int length;
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) >0){
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
            this.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

I am calling this class method in my splash screen as below

```
  @SuppressWarnings("read-database")                    
            DbFromAssets readdb= new DbFromAssets(SplashActivity.this);
```

This is working perfectly at my side i tested in emulator and available devices like lg sprint, motorolo droid,etc. i did not get the issues even once but i am getting force close reports in google play account. Can any body have idea why it is giving error. Please advice me it will improve my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add this table after first deploy on the market?

Comment: No i added before the market deploy.

Comment: What is the size of your predefined db?

Comment: 407 Kb only.And my file extension is .db. Is there any problem with this much size db file.

Comment: Why don't you use checkDataBase() as in an example?

Comment: by googlinn i got some info like this is device specific. only will appear in droid HD devices. please see this tread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585790/problem-with-testing-and-debuging-of-android-apps

Comment: No problem my above code will execute only once at very first time of installation app.

Comment: >>No problem my above code will execute only once at very first time of installation app<<

Why do you think so?

Comment: Yes i am copying database very first time only.that is in splash screen